# After filtering an array, object properties cannot be referenced?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following Angular controller:

```
app.controller('VideoCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $sce) {
$scope.videos = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Balance Training',
        source: 'http://powersk01.uic-chp.org/balance.mp4'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Pipette Training',
        source: 'http://powersk01.uic-chp.org/pipette.mp4'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Titration Training',
        source: 'http://powersk01.uic-chp.org/titration.mp4'
    }
];

$scope.video = $scope.videos.filter(function(video) {
    return video.id == $stateParams.videoId;
});
});
```

And in the view I try to display the video title:

```
<ion-view view-title="Video">
    <ion-content>
        <h1>{{ video.title }}</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

But for some reason `video.title` is undefined. I can place a debug point just after it filters the video and even though the console outputs the object and shows the properties available I cannot reference them. I have tried `video.title` and `video["title"]`.

This does work however:

```
$scope.video = $scope.videos[0];
```

Any idea why this would happen after I filter?

Comment: `filter` returns an array, not a single element.

Comment: I feel foolish, that was the problem. Thanks @JamesBuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter()` method of `Array` objects returns a *sub-array of all elements that pass the filter*, not a single object:

```
[1,2,3,4].filter(function(number) { return number > 2 })
 [3, 4]
```

That's why the value returned from your call to `filter()` doesn't have the properties you want. The `find()` method, on the other hand, returns the first element to pass the test:

```
[1,2,3,4].find(function(number) { return number > 2 })
 3
```

Use `find()` instead of `filter()`, or take `.filter()[0]` to get the first element.